# Parallax Effect UIScrollView ShowYou

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, parallax

I was looking at the latest update to the ShowYou application, and the parallax effect they have implemented is absolutely amazing.  I am playing around with UITableView and UIScrollView to see if I can sort of mimic it, but I wanted to see if I could touch base with some other folks to see how they would do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately ShowYou removed this implementation so it might be hard for people to know what you are talking about now :/